# Is it possible to abort sending of the e-mail somewhere in the middle of sending procedure?

Tags: hooks, emails

Mail sending is initiated in the depths of some third party module. There's a case when I need to intervenue and depending on some environment variables either let it through, or prevent it. How do I do that?

I've seen in the wild a weird technique of setting `$message['to']` to `+` (what's logic behind this by the way?). But this generates an error in server logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not confirmed about the proper and possible way. Can you try if it work? hook_mail_alter(&$message){ unset($message); }

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, why do you need to stop the messages based on environment variables?  Have you considered setting up a queue that you can filter?

Comment: I would like to, but mails get sent by the code that I do not control. I just need to stop them sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the documentation for [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7), you can avoid a message is sent by setting `$message['send']` to `FALSE`.

> #### Parameters
>
> - `$message`: An array containing the message data. Keys in this array include:
>
>   - 'id': The `drupal_mail()` id of the message. Look at module source code or `drupal_mail()` for possible id values.
>   - 'to': The address or addresses the message will be sent to. The formatting of this string will be validated with the PHP e-mail validation filter.
>   - 'from': The address the message will be marked as being from, which is either a custom address or the site-wide default email address.
>   - 'subject': Subject of the email to be sent. This must not contain any newline characters, or the email may not be sent properly.
>   - 'body': An array of strings containing the message text. The message body is created by concatenating the individual array strings into a single text string using "\n\n" as a separator.
>   - 'headers': Associative array containing mail headers, such as From, Sender, MIME-Version, Content-Type, etc.
>   - 'params': An array of optional parameters supplied by the caller of `drupal_mail()` that is used to build the message before `hook_mail_alter()` is invoked.
>   - 'language': The language object used to build the message before `hook_mail_alter()` is invoked.
>   - 'send': **Set to `FALSE` to abort sending this email message**.

At least, your code should check the value of `$message['id']` which is a concatenation of the short name of the module and the key assigned to the message from the module.

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'modulename_messagekey') {

    // Verify other conditions are true.

    $message['send'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
function hook_mail_alter(&$message){

    // Some logic here to test if you want to abort the mail
    $message['send'] = false;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. At least add a sentence or two of explanation.